# How to find IP address of HDP-Sandbox(on VirtualBox VM)?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ip

My host is Ubuntu. When I log in to HDP-Sandbox

```
ip addr show
```

gives me

```
5: eth0@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.2/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
```

Does it mean that

```
172.18.0.2
```

is the IP address of the VM?

I added this line to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com
```

When I look at logs

```
00:00:00.942935 NAT: Guest address guess set to 10.0.2.15 by initialization
00:00:00.943051 NAT: resolv.conf: nameserver 127.0.0.53
00:00:00.943058 NAT: resolv.conf: ignoring "options edns0"
00:00:00.943067 NAT: DNS server 127.0.0.53 registration detected, switching to the DNS proxy
```

The [network_nat](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) says

```
VM receives its network address and configuration on the private network from a DHCP server
```

How does this work in practice?
 Will I have static IP or not?